# Using IF ELSE Rule?

Tags: ampscript

New to Ampscript just FYI.

Trying to create an IF/Then statement so if a product has a rating it will call on the rating image 1-5 stars. If product rating info is not available it will not return that image. I've given the variable name 'productrating' and I've used > 1 because if the rating is greater than 1 it will result in true, otherwise it will result in false statement.

```
IF IndexOf(@productrating) > 1 Then

  SET @Result = "True"

Else

  SET @Result = "False"

EndIF
```

Comment: But what's your actual question? Where are you stuck? How can we assist you?

Comment: Sorry. I'm wondering if my statement is written correctly in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Logically you would set the expression to >= 1 right? Else your image wouldn't display any of the 1 star ratings?

Ideally, you would check using this logic:

If > 4 then show 5 star image
ElseIf > 3 then show 4 star image
ElseIf > 2 then show 3 star image
ElseIf > 1 then show 2 star image
ElseIf == 1 then show 1 star image
EndIf